# Youngs inequality for any power of X and Y

Tags: inequality

So I am working on a condition where I want to find the maximum "p" and "q" values for the Youngs inequality shown below . I am looking to find the $p$ and $q$ which  upper bounds $x^my^n$ by a weighted sum of $|x|^{2m}$ and  $|y|^{2n}$.

Such that :

\begin{equation}
xy \leq \frac{|x|^{p}}{p} + \frac{|y|^{q}}{q}
\end{equation}

How would I compute $p$ and $q$? where $ p > 1$ and $q > 1$?
In general, what would be the approach to start with such cases for any weighed sum like $|x|^{m+n}$ and  $|y|^{m+n}$ etc..? I do not know where to approach the problem from, although I can prove the Youngs inequality for $p=q=2$.